# How to load different viewcontrollers depending on current time (using -(void)didTap...)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a button that loads a viewcontroller on tap using

```
- (void)didTap_imageButton3:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  TramvajViewController *controller = [[TramvajViewController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
  [controller release];
}
```

How can I make it go to another controller in a specific time period (e.g. from midnight to 5)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the following

```
- (void)didTap_imageButton3:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];

    //Basing on the hour present a different view controller
    if (5 < hour && hour < 10) {
        TramvajViewController *controller = [[TramvajViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
        [controller release];
    }
    else {
        //Load other VC
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!
and thats in 24hr format, right?

Comment: @ValKalinic you are welcome, yes its in 24 H format

Comment: I won't, don't worry, I just have to finish what I'm doing now to try it :)